# CRC32 not calculated right

Tags: c++, crc32

I use a very simple algorithm to calculate the CRC32 but it gives wrong values.

I compare my output values with [calculator](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html) ones but it always looks different

```
unsigned int crc32_tab[256] = {
        0x00000000, 0x77073096, 0xee0e612c, 0x990951ba, 0x076dc419, 0x706af48f,
        0xe963a535, 0x9e6495a3, 0x0edb8832, 0x79dcb8a4, 0xe0d5e91e, 0x97d2d988,
        0x09b64c2b, 0x7eb17cbd, 0xe7b82d07, 0x90bf1d91, 0x1db71064, 0x6ab020f2,
        0xf3b97148, 0x84be41de, 0x1adad47d, 0x6ddde4eb, 0xf4d4b551, 0x83d385c7,
      .........,..............,.............,.........,...........
    };
```

Function that use the lookup table is

```
 unsigned int MyClass::crc32(unsigned int crc, const void *buf, unsigned int   size)
{
const unsigned int *p;

p = (const quint8 *)buf;
crc = crc ^~ 0xFFFFFFFF;

while(size--)
{
    crc = this->crc32_tab[(crc ^ *p++) & 0xFF] ^ (crc >> 8);
}

return crc ^~ 0xFFFFFFFF;
}
```

I call it by this way

```
 QString test= QString::number(mclass.crc32(0, crcval, 6))
```

Comment: Aside from any actual problems your code may or may not have, what precisely does `^~ 0xFFFFFFFF` accomplish?

Comment: Actually this step has no impact as if the bit with zero value it will remain 0 and if 1 it will remain same also

Comment: That was precisely my point. You're XORing with the complement of all-ones, which is all-zeros, which is to say you're doing nothing. If you had intended to complement the bits, you should use `x = ~x;`. As for the rest of your code, are you sure it's not computing a bit-reversed result? Using the right polynomial (CRC-32/Ethernet vs. CRC-32C/Castagnoli)?

Comment: The calculator you're using seems to use the CRC-32 Ethernet generator polynomial.

Comment: Yes I used it but is the other calculator use another CRC-32 ? What is the different between them?

Comment: There is no single CRC-32. There's in fact an entire family of CRC-32 algorithms, each differing in their _generator polynomial_. A different generator polynomial of course means they produce different checksums for the same data, and that their implementation will use different lookup table values. The two most popular CRC-32 algorithms are probably **CRC-32** (Ethernet, generator polynomial `0x04C11DB7`) and **CRC-32C** (Castagnoli, `0x1EDC6F41`).

Comment: I am using Ethernet one and I think the calculator I used as reference use it so.Am I right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82416/discussion-between-tulipe-and-iwillnotexist-idonotexist).

Comment: Why is this tagged qt?

Comment: @HamishMoffatt Probably because the code in question is called from a Qt C++ application. However, given that the problem turned out to have nothing to do with the Qt/non-Qt-ness of the application, I'd probably retag it [c++] plus any other relevant tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Solution drawn from chat dicussion*

The CRC-32 algorithm being implemented is **CRC-32 Ethernet** (generator polynomial `0x04C11DB7`).

This CRC-32 requires:

- Being initialized with `0xFFFFFFFF`.
- And being finalized by XORing with `0xFFFFFFFF`.

Therefore, you should remove the `crc ^~ 0xFFFFFFFF` statements within your function, pass `0xFFFFFFFF` on your call to the function, and once you're done CRCing the data, you should XOR the return value with `0xFFFFFFFF`.